# postResolve not called during collision detection in Box2D

Tags: box2d, collision-detection

I am using Cocos2d-x 2.0.2 and the Box2D associated with it. I create a derivative from b2ContactListner to detection collision. I need to know the contact position and impulse. Now the problem is my derivative BeginContact(), EndContact(), and preSolve() are all called while postSolve() is not called any more. Is this due to some property configuration when setup b2Body or it just can't call postSolve() because no collision resolve event happen? If no collision resolve event happen, how can I get collision impulse from other three callback functions? Thanks.

Comment: `PostSolve` is only called for contacts that are touching. Check `IsTouching()` of contact in `PreSolve`, and say result, please.

Comment: If one of the colliding objects is a Sensor then the `postSolve()` is not called.